# how to run multiple python files in selenium from a python automation using commands?

Tags: python, visual-studio, selenium, web-scraping, automation

I need to run multiple python files (which I can do, but I can't run them at the same time simultaneously), however, these files are running selenium, and I can't get them to work (without selenium they run normally, but when it comes to it's web scrapping it doesn't work at all). After researching I realized that a lot is said about selenium not being suitable for this task. I would like to know if there is any way for this to work, if I can make a python file run others in selenium simultaneously, if not, is there any other language or plugin that does this? I'm looking to know if the puppeteer performs this task, so any information is essential!!

Comment: Python is not capable of multithreading, but you can do so with Java which also has Selenium. I'm just not sure what you are trying to do with Selenium so it's hard to recommend something else without code etc.

Comment: example:
```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6v6-69Zzc0Q')
time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
exit()
```
let's suppose I want to open this same .py 20 times and make it run simultaneously, would java be the best language then?

Comment: @data_sc `Python is not capable of multithreading` this is not correct. If you are referring to the GIL, that's a bit of a deep topic, but it doesn't make this statement true. Especially for selenium where python spends most of it's time waiting on the browser anyway.